# Custom Keras Projection Layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, layer

I currently have data being outputted in R^n+m and I want to add a layer "projecting" the output vectors to R^m, ie:

```
(x_1,...,x_m+n) -> (x_n+1,...,x_m+n).
```

How can I write a custom tensorflow layer which does this, nothing trainable, given that I always know n?

I'm assuming that it's some type of Lambda layer...

Comment: Do you mean that you have a vector of length n+m and you want to slice out only last n element of your vector?

Comment: Yes, so if I have N data-points, each of length n+m, I would like the layer this to N data points each only outputting its last m elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you ask, given your vector of length 7 = n+m, and your m is 3 (slicing last 3 elements).

Input

```
[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.]
 [ 7.  8.  9. 10. 11. 12. 13.]]
```

Sample code

```
m = 3

test = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, -m:])
in1 = Input(shape=(7,))
out = test(in1)

# test
M = Model(inputs=[in1],outputs=[out])
M.compile(keras.optimizers.Adam(),loss='mse')
print(M.predict(np.arange(14,dtype=np.float32).reshape(2,7)))
```

Output

```
[[ 4.  5.  6.]
 [11. 12. 13.]]
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks, you really make it look easy! :)